The chart is not in the correct position
I have a big problem. I am adding a column chart in Latext and I want to add text below it and continue, but the column chart is thrown at the very end of the document. What is the reason and how do I solve it?
\documentclass[12pt,man]{apa7}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float} % Floats için
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % pgfplots versiyon uyumluluğu
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{İçindekiler}

\begin{document}

\section*{Aile Katılımına Engel Olan Faktörler}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={Bilgi Eksikliği, Zaman ve Maddi Kısıtlamalar, Psikolojik Faktörler},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            ymin=0, ymax=100,
            xlabel={Katılım Engelleri},
            ylabel={Katılımcı Oranı (\%)},
            bar width=15pt,
            width=\textwidth,
            height=8cm
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(Bilgi Eksikliği, 50) (Zaman ve Maddi Kısıtlamalar, 40) (Psikolojik Faktörler, 10)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Ailelerin Özel Eğitim Sürecine Katılımındaki Engeller}
    \label{fig:katilim_engelleri}
\end{figure}
\section*{Sonuç}
Aile katılımı, çocukların özel eğitim süreçlerinde daha hızlı öğrenmelerine, akademik hedeflerine ulaşmalarına ve genel gelişimlerine önemli ölçüde katkı sağlamaktadır. Bununla birlikte, aile desteğinin eksik olduğu durumlarda çocukların eğitim başarısında düşüş gözlenmektedir. Bu nedenle, aile katılımını artırmaya yönelik stratejiler geliştirilmesi kritik öneme sahiptir.

\end{document}


you placed the chart in a figure the only purpose of figure is to allow the content to be moved to help with page breaking,. then you used [h!] which is an option that means do not allow this at the top or bottom or on a page on its own (as no t b or p) so the figure has nowhere it may be placed and so goes to the end.

This might helo:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15036

You need to add floatsintext when using man with apa7.  See section 7.2 (page 11) of the manual.
